# Hide and Show number of rows in a table that are sharing the same ID

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I'm generating rows dynamically, I've added an ID value to `<tr>` tag, therefore each generated row has got the same ID. The problem is when I try to hide and show these rows, it's only hiding and showing the first row, even though there are many more.

```
 <tr style="color: lightgrey; display: none" id="deletedTrainingRecords">
                        <td>@d</td>
                        <td>@e.TrainingDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>@e.DateAdded.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>@e.AddedBy</td>

                        <td class="@cls[0]"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="fa fa-flag-o" style="cursor: default" title="Deleted Record"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: `row has got the same ID` ***ID should always be UNIQUE***

Comment: @guradio Is there a way to mark a group of elements in order to show them and hide them?

Comment: use class and index to tell which tr you are referring to

Comment: When adding the rows dynamically can you possibly increment a variable and include that in the ID. For example `id="row#"` where # is the variable.

Comment: it is a bad solution if he wants to access all of them in one time

Comment: @LockeDonohoe How would I attach an event later on to all these elements with different ID's?

Comment: @NaughtyNinja best way is use class and you can just use index to access them individually

Comment: Sorry, I thought you needed to hide them individually. Like guradio suggested assign a class and perform the function on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code on your event that handle the show and hide

```
$(document).find("tr#deletedTrainingRecords").each(function(){
   //dosomething
})
```

if can, avoid using same id's explained in [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really) ,you can change the id into class. and change the above selectors from `tr#deletedTraingRecords` into `tr.deletedTrainingRecords`

```
$(document).find("tr.deletedTrainingRecords").each(function(){
   //dosomething
})
```

or

like Locke saids change them into class and then

`$(".deletedTrainingRecords").show() or .hide()`

Answer (score 1):

as guradio said the ID has to be unique. use class instead of ID and then you can call `document.getElementsByClassName` or `$(".className")` to reach those elements

Answer (score -1):

If you had provided the code to hide the row, would have been great. in jquery you can use below line of code.

$('#deletedTrainingRecords').hide(

Comment: and it will hide only first row as $('#anyID') returns max one element